# how to rename file from sdcard/newfolder in android

Tags: android

I have a file in directory called sdcard/newfolder. I want to rename files from newfolder directory. I have following line of code its working for files from sdcard but not for newfolder.

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,("a.txt"));
File to = new File(sdcard,("b.txt"));
from.renameTo(to);
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi! You can format source-code by putting 4 spaces before each lines *(the `{}` button on top of the editor does just that)* -- I've done it for you this time ;-) see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more informations about formating.

Answer (score 0):

If the new folder doesn't exist yet, you have to create it, like this:

```
File dir = new File(sdcard, (folderpath));
if (!(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()))
    dir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Shekhar: well the problem is you are getting variable which is pointing to sdcard/ and it will not work for any folder unless you use above code or you can also write File iFile = new File("/sdcard/NewFolder/"); .... hope this helps...

Comment: @Farhan - thanks, but, `File iFile = new File("/sdcard/NewFolder/");` will not create the folder, also, the external storage device is not necessarily `/sdcard/`